VisualForce Markup to open salesforce report using its name
I am new to learning apex code and have a scenario where we need to open a salesforce tabular report using the report's name. I have created VF tab, visualforce page and kept the tab in homepage already. Below is what I tried in VisualForce Markup and a new page opens but doesn't display the report. Could you please help me with what I could be missing. I appreciate it!
`<apex:page>

<script>
var reportName = "Employee Info";
var result = sforce.connection.query(
"SELECT ID "+
"FROM Report " + 
"WHERE Name = '" +reportName+ "' " +
"LIMIT 1"
);

var URL = '/'+result;
var win = window.open(URL,"target=_blank");
window.history.back();

</script>

</apex:page>`

Below is what I tried in VisualForce Markup and a new page opens but doesn't display the report. Could you please help me with what I could be missing. I appreciate it!
<apex:page>
<script>
var reportName = "Employee Info"; var result = sforce.connection.query( "SELECT ID "+ "FROM Report " +  "WHERE Name = '" +reportName+ "' " + "LIMIT 1" );  var URL = '/'+result; var win = window.open(URL,"target=_blank"); window.history.back(); 
</script>
</apex:page>

To open report you should pass report Id to url , but you actually pass something that is return from sforce.connection.query. You should first get id from result and then pass it to the url.
var reportId = result.getArray("record")[0].Id;
var URL = '/' + reportId;

